# How to re arrange child elements in an XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I have an xml file and I am looking to re position the child elements based on certain attributes ( value if "id" in the example below). 
I am looking to rewrite the xml file in a way that "bk103" would be the first child of . 
My question is not about how to sort the child elements ( it can be done with "if" condition). I was wondering if there is a way to parse the xml file and rewrite the elements back in the xml file in the order I would like it to be in ( say ascending order of book id)

what methods should I use to do this, also if anyone could suggest an algorithm to do the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>enter code here
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>


Output:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
<book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>


</catalog>
```

Comment: your current question is too broad.  break it into smaller bits and work on them individually.

Comment: I just edited the post to be a little more specific. let me know if it is clear enough

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an XML in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917133/sorting-an-xml-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use XQuery to rearrange your `<book/>` nodes in your XML.

```
declare variable $input-document external;

<catalog>
{
  for $book in doc($input-document)/catalog/book
  let $id := $book/data(@id)
  order by $id descending
  return $book
}
</catalog>
```

With an XQuery engine like [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) you transform the XML from the command line:

```
java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query input-document=input.xml reorder.xq
```

`saxon9he.jar` is the Saxon HE JAR, the XQuery variable `$input-document` is bound to `'input.xml'` calling the XQuery in file `reorder.xq`.

If you really need to call your XQuery from Java, you can do it with [XQJ](http://xqj.net/).

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQConnection;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQDataSource;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQException;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQPreparedExpression;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQSequence;

import net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQDataSource;


public class ReorderXml {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws XQException, IOException {

    // Use XQJ to execute an XQuery with Saxon HE
    XQDataSource ds = new SaxonXQDataSource();
    XQConnection conn = ds.getConnection();

    // InputStream for the XQuery
    InputStream query = new FileInputStream("reorder.xq");

    // Create a prepared expression ...
    XQPreparedExpression exp = conn.prepareExpression(query);

    // ... and bind the path to the input document to XQuery variable $input-document
    exp.bindString(new QName("input-document"), "data/input.xml", null);

    // Execute the query and ...
    XQSequence xqs = exp.executeQuery();

    // ... print the resulting document to standard out.
    xqs.writeSequence(System.out, null);

    // Clean up (production code should do that in a finally clause!)
    xqs.close();
    conn.close();
    query.close();
  }

}
```

There are also some other XQuery engines like [Zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/) and [MXQuery](http://mxquery.org/).

Answer (score 0):

you would need a good xml parser for java. Then You can use that to create a new xml document with the arrangement of your choice. Actually MKYong has already covered both [Reading from an xml document](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) and [creating an xml document](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/) in java. He also covers retrieving the values inside attributes of elements.

Comment: I am using the DOM parsers. Is there a method in java that I could use to sort elements in a document?

Answer (score 0):

The following example reads a source file "xmlFile.xml", alphabetically reverse orders the book nodes and writes the result to a new file "newXmlFile.xml".

```
package org.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

public class XmlElementOrder {

    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String PATH_PREFIX = "src/main/resources/";
    private static final String SOURCE_FILE = "xmlFile.xml";
    private static final String TARGET_FILE = "newXmlFile.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException {

        File xmlFile = new File(PATH_PREFIX + SOURCE_FILE);
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document document = builder.build(xmlFile);

        Element rootElement = document.detachRootElement();
        List<Element> children = new ArrayList<Element>(rootElement.getChildren());
        rootElement.removeContent();

        Comparator<Element> comparator = new Comparator<Element>() {
            public int compare(Element o1, Element o2) {
                return o2.getAttributeValue(ID).compareTo(o1.getAttributeValue(ID));
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(children, comparator);

        Document newDocument = new Document(rootElement);
        rootElement.addContent(children);

        XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
        xmlOutput.output(newDocument, new FileWriter(PATH_PREFIX + TARGET_FILE));

    }
}
```

The example uses the [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) library. If you are using Maven you can include it in your POM as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: am getting Null pointer at  return o2.getAttributeValue(ID).compareTo(o1.getAttributeValue(ID));  . How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the comparator with this:

```
        Comparator<Element> comparator = (op1,op2) -> op2.getChildText(ID).compareTo(op1.getChildText(ID));
```

Simone